# Compile unreferenced package with exported functions

Tags: ada

In a project mixing Ada and C, I define and export Ada functions to be called in the C program. The compile chain is complex and I don't have a possibility to make any change to it but when I compile the project, the package containing the exported function and thus not called by any Ada code is completely left out by the compiler. This mean that the linker can't do its work as it missing external function.

For example this simple three files project :

`Main.adb`

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Hello ada community");
end Main;
```

`test.ads`

```
package Test is

    procedure Hello
        with Export     => True,
             Convention => C,
             Link_Name  => "test_hello";

end Test;
```

`test.adb`

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body Test is

    procedure Hello is
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Hello world");
    end Hello;

end Test;
```

When I compile my project, the package Test is ignored by the compiler. Is there a pragma to force the compiler to export the symbols and compile the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution which was quite obvious. I just have to include the package in the main.adb file.

Comment: Chances are you are using GNAT, which forms the library "on the fly" during the build, so it links only units that are actually involved in the project. This is possible thanks to Ada's modularity.

Comment: @Louise: You can also accept your own answer if it solves your problem! In that way other will clearly see that there is a solution when browsing this site.

Comment: `with Test; pragma Unreferenced (Test);` to avoid warnings about unused `Test`. (`Unreferenced` is a GNAT pragma, not in the Standard).

Comment: @Lii will do, I have to wait two days before, according to stackoverflow rules.